# Escaping HTML to insert as data-attribute (Bootstrap Popover, Rails)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, escaping

I'm trying to use rails helper as a source for data-content attribute of Bootstrap Popover. All things come together inside of Rails helper:

```
content_tag :span, "Something", data: { toggle: "popover", trigger: "hover", content: some_helper }
```

`some_helper` produces a list (styled by bootstrap):

```
<ul class="list-group">...</ul>
```

And the issue is that class="..." inside of data attribue breaks the markup. So there should be some way to escape double quotes `\"` or to force rails helper using single quotes. Or any better solution?

Comment: `content_tag :span, "Something", data: { toggle: "popover", trigger: "hover", content: some_helper.html_safe }` may help you

Comment: I tried that and it didn't help, but what did help (weirdly) is html_escape_once wrapping some_helper output.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how, but it worked with `html_escape_once(some_helper)`. Given that I wrapped it with `h()` initially and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= content_tag :span, "Something", data: { toggle: "popover", trigger: "hover"} do %>
  <%= some_helper %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: How exactly the output of some_helper will get to data-content attribute here? But what is interesting, I'm not sure how it's going to work. The api of content_tag assumes that content provided either in second parameter or as a result of the block (if given) :) Who will win here...